# npm, avoid publishing of src dir without using .npmignore

Tags: npm, npm-publish

The [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish)
command creates a tarball (with `src` dir) and publish it to registry.

is there a way to exclude the `src` dir avoiding use of [`.npmignore`](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d) ?

Comment: Can you provide context as to why you would need to avoid using .npmignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm provides no other built-in feature to achieve that, so a custom solution is required.

If you really don't want to use [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) to keep the `src` directory out of your published package, then consider utilizing `pre` and `post` hooks in your [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) instead.

The pertinent hooks are:

> - `prepublishOnly`: Run BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on `npm publish` ...
> - `postpublish`: Run AFTER the package is published.

#### For *nix platforms

1. Add a `prepublishOnly` script to the `scripts` section of your *package.json* that moves the `src` directory to another location outside of your project directory prior to publishing.
2. Also, add a `postpublish` script that moves the `src` directory back to the project directory when publishing has completed.
3. Run `npm publish` (as per normal) to publish your package.

For instance:

**package.json**

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "prepublishOnly": "mv src/ ../",
  "postpublish": "mv ../src .",
  ...
},
...
```

**Note:** You'll need to ensure that no other `src` folder/directory exists at the path location you choose to temporarily move the `src` directory to via your `prepublish` script.

#### Cross platform:

For a cross-platform solution consider utilizing [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx). This package includes a portable `mv` command. In which case, configure your `prepublish` and `postpublish` scripts something like the following instead:

**package.json**

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "prepublishOnly": "shx mv src/ ../",
  "postpublish": "shx mv ../src .",
  ...
},
...
```

Comment: What about package.json `files` property?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `files` property in your package.json to explicitly include the files you want to publish.

```json
{
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "index.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @RobC answer, there is no other way then a custom solution for avoid using .npmignore.

Since I’m using the publish command in a Jenkins pipeline, a solution is to create a temporary .npmignore while the publish step directly in the Jenkinsfile:

```
echo "src/" >> .npmignore
echo "*.js" >> .npmignore
echo "*.json" >> .npmignore
echo "Jenkinsfile" >> .npmignore
curl --insecure -u ${USERPASS} 'https://my-repo/api/npm/auth' >> /home/jenkins/.npmrc
npm publish --registry https:// my-repo/api/npm/npm-local/
```